# Why is the .Clear() function clearing the wrong list?

Tags: c#, list

```
public void ConvertMoves()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < maxDirections; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("gimme tsMoves "+tSpossibleMoves[i].Count +  " from " + this);
        possibleAttacks[i] = tSpossibleAttacks[i];
        possibleAttacksInactive[i] = tSpossibleAttacksInactive[i];
        possibleAttackIndicators[i] = tSpossibleAttackIndicators[i];
        possibleMoves[i] = tSpossibleMoves[i];
        Debug.Log("Gimme moves(1) " + possibleMoves[i].Count + " from " + this);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < maxDirections; i++)
    {
        tSpossibleAttacks[i].Clear();
        tSpossibleAttacksInactive[i].Clear();
        tSpossibleAttackIndicators[i].Clear();
        tSpossibleMoves[i].Clear();
        Debug.Log("Gimme moves(2) " + possibleMoves[i].Count + " from " + this);
    }
}
```

so the Debug Log reports the following:

> gimme tsMoves 2 from JeanArc(Clone) (JeanArc)
>   Gimme moves(1) 2 from JeanArc(Clone) (JeanArc)

sofar everything is doing fine but then...

> Gimme moves(2) 0 from JeanArc(Clone) (JeanArc)

why does it clear the moves of whole different List variable ?

Comment: Read something about how reference types work in C#. When you assign `possibleAttacks[i] = tSpossibleAttacks[i]` you're not making a copy of data but assinging a reference

Comment: Oh interesting what is the fasted way to go about this?

Comment: should i itereate through every piece of information?

Comment: See Heinzi's comment to John's answer. What you want is called a "deep copy".

Comment: [C# Concepts: Value vs Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) A really suggested read before going on

Comment: You could read something about [prototype](https://www.dofactory.com/net/prototype-design-pattern) pattern and specifically its `Clone()` method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't create a copy of the list item:

```
possibleAttacks[i] = tSpossibleAttacks[i]
```

It simply copies the *reference* to the same object into a second variable, so `possibleAttacks[i]` and `tSpossibleAttacks[i]` now both point to the same item in memory. Think of it like having two credit cards to access one bank account.

You can read more about reference types [here in Microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types).

As Heinzi pointed out in the comment below, you can copy your item (as it's a list) by calling:

```
possibleAttacks[i] = tSpossibleAttacks[i].ToList();
```

By the way, if you just want to assign `tSpossibleAttacks[i]` and then reset it, you could also just do this:

```
possibleAttacks[i] = tSpossibleAttacks[i];
tSpossibleAttacks[i] = new List<your_type_name_here>(); // this will overwrite the reference held by `tSpossibleAttacks[i]`.
```

Note that if your list contains reference types, you have a similar problem within the list, for example:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

List<Test> list1 = new List<Test>();
list1.Add(new Test() { Name = "John" });
List<Test> list2 = list1.ToList();
Console.WriteLine(list1[0].Name); // John
Console.WriteLine(list2[0].Name); // John
list2[0].Name = "Fred";
Console.WriteLine(list1[0].Name); // Fred
Console.WriteLine(list2[0].Name); // Fred
```

So I'd recommend reading up on value types vs reference types and how references work in C#.

Comment: How to fix it: If you want to create a copy, you can do so with `possibleAttacks[i] = tSpossibleAttacks[i].ToList()`.

Comment: it says there is no function called "ToList()"

Comment: `.ToList();` is a LINQ extension method. If you're using .NET core in Visual Studio, the using isn't included in the .cs file by default, so you need to add `using System.Linq;` at the top.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

What @John said. You need to copy the lists.

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxDirections; i++)
{
    Debug.Log("gimme tsMoves "+tSpossibleMoves[i].Count +  " from " + this);
    possibleAttacks[i] = tSpossibleAttacks[i];
    tSpossibleAttacks[i] = new List<T>;

    possibleAttacksInactive[i] = tSpossibleAttacksInactive[i];
    tSpossibleAttacksInactive[i] = new List<U>();

    possibleAttackIndicators[i] = tSpossibleAttackIndicators[i];
    tSpossibleAttackIndicators[i] = new List<V>();

    possibleMoves[i] = tSpossibleMoves[i];
    tSpossibleMoves[i] = new List<Z>();

    Debug.Log($"Gimme moves(1), i={i}: {possibleMoves[i].Count} from {this}");
    Debug.Log($"Gimme moves(2)  i={i}: {tpossibleMoves[i].Count} from {this}");
}
```

Example:

```
var l1 = new List<string>();
List<string> l2;

l1.Add("One");
l1.Add("Two");

l2 = l1;
l1 = new List<string>();
l1.Add("Three");

Console.WriteLine("L1:");
foreach (var elem in l1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(elem);
}
Console.WriteLine("L2:");
foreach (var elem in l2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(elem);
}
```

This prints:

```
L1:
Three
L2:
One
Two
```